# how to move vertex groups in animation

Tags: animation

Ok so I have a single model that's made up of vertex groups (quite a few) my goal is to have an animation with 5 different positions and instant movement of vertex groups at the occurrence of each frame with a new position. (basically a gif like animation)

here is a view of the project: [image]

The body and Head are one group while there's 60ish cubes for the legs and tail that have to move and form different cube shapes.

I made sure that Each cube is completely separated so they won't cause problems when moved.

I've never animated anything in blender before and have no idea how to use shape keys or anything like that (I tried but failed >.<)

Some help animating this master piece would be great!!!

(btw the 2 extra cubes floating there are needed later) I don't know what do do with the extra cubes while animating either :P bonus Q.

Comment: An armature is not suitable here ? Have you tried that ?

Comment: I have no idea what an armature is

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that the individual vertex groups don't need to move fluidly at all (think gif)

Comment: How many groups do you have here ?

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be any advantage in having vertex groups for something like this. Vertex groups are helpful for isolating selections and eventually for forms of deformations which you will discover along the way.

For now you might use the vertex groups to select and then create separate objects - the  <kbd>P</kbd>  key ... 
[image: P for create new object]

...that you then can keyframe with the  <kbd>I</kbd>  key.

[image: I for insert keyframe]

Comment: It has to stay a single model.

Comment: For a particular reason? You might parent them to one object that they function as a single model...